# PgAdmin4 (Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I came across a problem that I encountered when using pgAdmin4 to connect to a PostgreSQL server. When trying to establish a connection, the following error occurs: "Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired."
I just want to create a new server and this error pops up, can anyone help?
[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGxJT.png)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: pgAdmin4 cannot create the database server itself it can only connect to existing servers. Head over to https://www.postgresql.org/download/ to download a postgresql server.